# Get JSON data to angularJS module

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json

I am trying to bind json data to angular module. Following is my code.

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
  app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get("list.php").then(function(response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data.records; 
    });
  });
</script> 

    <div class="col-md-12"><!--col 1-->
       <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="z in myData">
          {{ z.Type }}
        </li>
      </ul>
```

And my list.php file,

```
<?php    
include_once("mysql_db/db.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM taxitype";
$data = retrieve($sql); // This execute mysqli functions and return an array
echo json_encode($data);  
?>
```

But it is now displaying list in HTML file. What can be the reason?
Is their any special way to create json objects for angularJS?

Comment: can you paste your JSON , which return by your API?

Comment: [{"Code":"1","Type":"Luxuary","MinFee":"2000.00","DayRate":"50.00"},{"Code":"2","Type":"sample","MinFee":"300.00","DayRate":"200.00"},{"Code":"3","Type":"Economy","MinFee":"2000.00","DayRate":"45.00"},{"Code":"4","Type":"sdf","MinFee":"456.00","DayRate":"454.00"},{"Code":"5","Type":"sfdsdfsdf","MinFee":"2323.00","DayRate":"2323.00"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write `response.data` instead of `response.data.records`. as your JSON is an `array` not `object`.

See `$http` service [response object properties](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#overview).

Here is your updated code.

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
  app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get("list.php").then(function(response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data; 
    });
  });
</script> 

    <div class="col-md-12"><!--col 1-->
       <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="z in myData">
          {{ z.Type }}
        </li>
      </ul>
```